# Prove that the sum of distances from any point on an ellipse to its foci is constant in this framework

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, solution-verification, conic-sections

A conic section with eccentricity $e$ is defined as :

> Given a line L, a point $F$ not on $L$, and a positive number $e$. Let $d(X,L)$ denote the distance from a point $X$ to $L$. The set of all $X$ satisfying the relation $$\|X-F\| = e \cdot d(X,L)$$
> is called a conic section with eccentricity $e$. The conic is called an ellipse if $e < 1$.

Now, taking a vector $N$ normal to $L$ with $\|N\| = 1$, we have $d(X,L) = |(X-P) \cdot N|$ with $P$ being any point on $L$, so the equation becomes $$\|X-F\| = e  |(X-P) \cdot N|$$

Now, for an ellipse $(X-P) \cdot N$ is always negative or positive according to the choice of $N$.

Setting $P$ to be that point on $L$ nearest to $F$,and positioning $F$ in the negative half plane (in the sense that $(F-P) \cdot N < 0$,  we get that $P-F = dN$ with $d = \|P-F\|$. So we can rewrite the basic relation as

$$\|X-F\| = e  |(X-F) \cdot N - d|$$

This was the **background**, I wrote it to make it clear to you and to me :D

---

From here, I want to show that, if a conic is an ellipse with center at the origin then

$$\|X-F\| + \|X+F\|= 2a$$

with $a = ed+eF \cdot N$. Namely that the sum of distances from any point on an ellipse to its foci is constant.

**Attempt** :

if $F$ is on the negative half plane then $(X-F) \cdot N - d < 0$, so the basic relation can be written as

$$\|X-F\| = e  (d - (X-F) \cdot N ) = ed+eF\cdot N -eX\cdot N = a -eX\cdot N$$

Now we can see that $$eX\cdot N + a = e((X+F)\cdot N + d)  \stackrel{?}{=} \|X+F\|$$

If I was able to establish the last equality then it would be done, but I'm not able to do it.

---

Now, I saw that the problem involved a **simmetric** relation about the origin so if it works for $X$ it works also for $-X$, then substituting in the basic relation we get

$$\|X+F\| = e  |(X+F) \cdot N + d| = e  ((X+F) \cdot N + d) $$

because $(-X-F) \cdot N - d < 0$ . So , we have proven the theorem. Is this right?

Comment: Is there only one given line $L?$

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: So how do you get two foci from a single given line?

Comment: I think the foci are $F$ and $-F$ in the case of a simmetric relation about the origin, isn't it?

Comment: That means there are two lines from which perpendicular distances are taken.

Comment: You forgot to set the origin at the center of the ellipse. As written, the result is false.

Comment: yes, I agree with you, I change it

Comment: Your ellipse is given by $L$, $F$ and $e$, how do you know its center is in the origin? You should explain where the center is located, and then set the origin there, if you want.

Comment: Moreover, as I wrote in a comment to an answer below, you cannot take for granted that a second pair focus+directrix exists: this should (and can) be proved. Once you have proved that, you are done.

Comment: About the center, can I take the center as the point with $y$ coordinate equal to the one of $F$ and $x$ coordinate the mean of the $x$ coordinate of the point $X$ at the minimum distance from the directrix and the point at the maximum distance from the directrix? ( I think I know how to actually found this coordinate in terms of $L,F$ and $e$)

Comment: Yes, that is the correct definition: the center is the midpoint of the two points on line $PF$ belonging to the ellipse.

Comment: Is it not enough setting the origin there as you said? (It doesn't seem to me that my attempt uses the second directrix) thanks a lot for the help anyway

Comment: You don't use the second directrix, but you assume that the ellipse is symmetric about its center, which is equivalent.

Comment: Here's for instance a possible proof of the ellipse symmetry (see first part of the answer): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3606297/255730

Comment: thanks a lot ! @intelligenti pauca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parallel line directrices which are separated by constant distance $D_1 D_2 = u_1+ u_2$ symmetrically placed about origin on both sides.

[image]

Multiply the relation by $e$ so that for a new constant $a$

$$ 2 a = e u_1+ e u_2 $$

which proves the given proposition.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what $u_1$ and  $u_2$ are referring to, can you give me some more detail?

Comment: Sorry. Included the  picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can I ask you if you think my method is right(even if it's very ugly)?

Comment: In your answer you take for granted that a second pair focus+directrix exists. How do you prove that?

Comment: Sought claification  from OP..